# Excel Formula to calculate hours from budget

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that will calculate the number of hours we can allow for each department. If Monthly budget is $8000 and average hourly wage is $10.44 how many hours a day can I allow? If I have 5 employees how many hours can I give each employee?

Comment: I have the spreadsheet almost finished, I am just confused on the actual hours per day I can allot.

Comment: 8000/(10.44*5*number of days)

Answer (score 0):

consider the following screenshot

[image]

Divide the budget by the average wage with `=b3/b4`

Divide the result by 5 to arrive at the number of hours per employee `=b5/5`

Comment: Thank you for taking time out of your day to answer my question. I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as the answer as described in the [Tour]. That's how you can say thanks around here.